# How to create project in the terminal of Eclipse Che

Tags: eclipse-che

For creating new projects,
I'd like to copy "the Java project" or "the TypeScript project" in the terminal of Eclipse Che (for example, use scripting), and make them indicate on Eclipse Che as a new project.
In such case, what kind of procedure should be performed?

Answer (score 0):

You can git clone in the terminal in `/projects`. Such a project will be marked as Blank project type in Che. You can change project type afterwards.